# Multiple aggregates via join in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two tables

- Email Contact History
- Place of Service

that share a primarymembercustomerid. The Email Contact History has three fields:

- Campaigncode
- Primarymembercustomerid
- maildate

and the Place of Service table has three fields

- primarymembercustomerid
- servicedate
- serviceshortDesc

primarymembercustomerids are selected for E-mail campaigns, then if they walk into one of our branch offices and receive services, they show up in the Place of Service table. I want to count the number of primarymembercustomer ids that are mailed, and right next to it I want to have a count of primarymembercustomerids that showed up to a branch office.

What I have so far:

```
select
ch.campaigncode,
pos.serviceshortdesc,
count(ch.primarymembercustomerid),
count(pos.primarymembercustomerid)

from mktprodvm.cdmv_prmmbr_contacthist_email ch

right outer join mktprodvm.cdmv_pos pos on ch.primarymembercustomerid =        pos.primarymembercustomerid

where ch.campaigncode = 'EDT_ALLACMO'
and pos.servicedate between '2017-02-01' and '2017-02-28'

group by 1,2
```

What I'm ending up with is a count of primarymembercustomerids that walk into a branch for that time period, but I'm not getting the total count of primarymembercustomerids that were E-mailed. I thought that by doing a right outer join I would get the total number of primarymembercustomerids that were mailed, but it's not working for me. I feel like I need to do some kind of subquery or correlated subquery, but I've ready about how to use them and I don't think that's right. I've never used them before and to be quite honest I'm not that great of a SQL coder either. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you show your existing result, why it's wrong and what you actually want? The same number for `count(ch.primarymembercustomerid)` in each row, then it's `sum(count(ch.primarymembercustomerid)) over ()`?

Comment: I'm having trouble formatting my answer as a table, but right now my answer looks like (see next comment)

Comment: CampaignCode Count(PrimaryMemberCustomerID) Count(PrimaryMemberCustomerID)
EDT_ALLACMO     32,538 32,538

Comment: and it second column should be the number of people mailed, which is 171,000

Answer (score 0):

Because my low reputation on this site I can't comment, so I'm writing this as an answer.

I think that you are using the wrong type of join (or writing the tables in the wrong order). If you don't want to lose rows of your main table, the Email Contact History, you have to do a `LEFT JOIN` not a `RIGHT JOIN`.

Also, I don't know if it's possible, but I'm guessing that a `primarymembercustomerid` can have more than one service and since you are selecting the `serviceshortdesc`, a single Email might count in different rows of your anwerset and the total won't be accurate. According to what you said you want, I don't see a reason for including the service description in the SELECT.

Comment: I tried using a left outer join and still unfortunately I get the same results. Also you are right, I could simplify by excluding serviceshortdesc which would give me distinct counts but either way is fine.

Comment: @KevinMcQ Since you are using a filters that includes fields of both tables the result will be equal to an `INNER JOIN`, if `servicedate` can't be null you can try something like `(pos.servicedate between '2017-02-01' and '2017-02-28' OR pos.servicedate IS NULL)` using a `LEFT JOIN`.